# Jquery Datatables make rows selected

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable.I done it using http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html Now I want to make some rows selected when it comes from the controller.
Can anyone guide me to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending the data from controller, send a flag for selection and add ".selected" class in those

```
<tr role="row" class="odd selected">
    <td class="sorting_1">Airi Satou</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>2008/11/28</td>
    <td>$162,700</td>
</tr>
```